# jQuery: Run function if each tr has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a `table` where `tr`s are being assigned `class` with js.

I have another `div` that I want to reflect it on. However, my `each()` function doesn't seem to be working properly.

I have the following JS:

```
$("table.result tr").each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("red")) {
        $("#color").addClass("red");
        //bunch of other things
    } else {
        $("#color").addClass("green");
        //bunch of other things
    }
});
```

And this is my markup:

```
<table class="result">
   <tr class="red">
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Result</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="red">
       <td>John Doe</td>
       <td>Pass</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="red">
       <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
       <td>Pass</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="red">
       <td>Jane Doe</td>
       <td>Fail</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<div id="color"></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is, if all the `tr`s have a `class` of `red`, only then do I want the `div` to have the class of `red` too else it should be `green`. But the `jQuery` is only testing it on the last `tr` whether it has the `class` or not.

But it doesn't seem to be working. It's probably a very small mistake but I cannot figure it out. Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/okvv330L/6/

As you can see, since one `tr` does not have the `class` `red`, the `div` should be `green`. But it's only checking the last `tr` and basing it on that.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about jquery but: If you have a red class and add a green class - is there some kind of sorting in the classes so that the added green is overwritten by the "old" red? Do you have to remove/change the red into green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using the following code:

```
var $rowCount = $('.result tr').length;
var $rowFill = 0;
$(".result tr").each(function() {
    if($(this).is('.red')) {
        $rowFill = $rowFill + 1;
    }
});
if($rowFill == $rowCount) {
    $('#color').addClass('red');
} else {
    $('#color').addClass('green');
}
```

Since the `each()` was only testing the last row; I got it to match the count with the number of rows. So now, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the original styling is overriding the style of the added class.
The easiest solution would be to add higher specficity like

```
.red, #color.red {
    background: red;
}
```

**Update**

> What I'm trying to do is, if all tr's have the class red, then give the div a class of red else give it green.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#color").addClass("green");
  $("table.result:not(:has(tr:not(.red))) + #color").addClass("red");
});
```

```css
#color {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.green,
#color.green{
  background: green;
}
.red,
#color.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="result">
  <tr class="red">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="green">
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>Pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="red">
    <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
    <td>Pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="red">
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>Fail</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="color"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I've fixed the styling but my problem still remains.

Comment: @AliIshaq, it is working in the code snippet in my answer, did you see it? Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net with the problem in it?

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/okvv330L/6/ where one TR does not have the class but it still executes the code.

Comment: I made use of class red and green for the sake of simplicity. There will be a lot of other things I will be doing so I want to run a function. My knowledge of js is limited, but I don't think I will be able to run other functions using this. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's working perfectly as it's adding the class .red in your div but it's just not taking the css as per the [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) as id has greater specificity than class.

So, you may use:

```
#color.red{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Or, you may use !important:

```
.red{
   color: #f00 !important;
}
```

[your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okvv330L/4/)

---

As per your comment, I have updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okvv330L/7/). You may use like this:

```
$(function() {
    if($("table.result tr.red").length == $("table.result tr").length) {
            $("#color").addClass("red");
        } else {
            $("#color").addClass("green");
        }
});
```

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle. Sorry about the css mistake but if you check the updated fiddle, the jquery still doesn't do what I want it to do: https://jsfiddle.net/okvv330L/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
change your css.use important tag
.green {
    background: green !important;
}
.red {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Fixed, but it doesn't solve my problem. Please check updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/okvv330L/6/

Comment: actually .each is replacing css class of div

Comment: But it's not testing every TR. How do I make it do that?

Comment: $(function() {
 $("table.result tr").each(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("red")) {
            $("#color").removeClass();
   $("#color").addClass("red");
  } else {
            $("#color").removeClass();
   $("#color").addClass("green");
            return false;
  }
 }); 
});

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since your want to assign the class `red` to `#color` only if all the `tr`s has the class `red`

In that case using  a loop will be wrong as it will always use the state of the last `tr`.

Also you have a problem with [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), where you have assigned a background color using ID property then that will have preference over the class rule you are assigning later, so you will have to make the class rule more specific by using a combination of the id rule and class rule.

```js
$(function() {
  var green = $("table.result tr").is(':not(.red)');
  $("#color").toggleClass("green", green);
  $("#color").toggleClass("red", !green);
});
```

```css
#color {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.green,
#color.green {
  background: green;
}
.red,
#color.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="result">
  <tr class="red">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="red">
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>Pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="red">
    <td>Johnathan Doe</td>
    <td>Pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="red">
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>Fail</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="color"></div>
```

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. What I'm trying to do is, if all tr's have the class red, then give the div a class of red else give it green.

Comment: That code works but I'm not trying to use toggleClass because I want to run other codes too. I made use of class for the sake of simplicity in explaining.

Comment: You can use the variable `green` to do the other things

Comment: Desperately trying to make it work but unable too. This is the actual code that I have: https://jsfiddle.net/boza34eh/ but it's not working properly :'(